# SAF: No Activity found to handle Intent - android.intent.action.OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE - Android 13

Tags: android, android-intent, storage-access-framework, android-storage

Just updated the app which works now only with SAF so users would be able to choose any directory they wish and app could work not just with media files (MediaStore is a useless thing).

But interesting thing I got in Firebase Crashlytics:

> Fatal Exception: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException No Activity
> found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE
> (has extras) }

for Galaxy A52 device on Android 13

Didn't expect that such things can be missing, especially on Android 13 devices.

How am I supposed to handle such errors? Can I even help users to fix such issues, mb suggest them to install one of File Browser apps from Goolge Play, will it help to choose directory with `android.intent.action.OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` for my app?

```
fun selectFolderSaf(
    activity: Activity,
    coroutineScope: CoroutineScope,
    activityResultLauncher: ActivityResultLauncher<Intent>,
) {
    val intent = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        val storageManager =
            activity.getSystemService(Context.STORAGE_SERVICE) as StorageManager
        storageManager.primaryStorageVolume.createOpenDocumentTreeIntent()
    } else {
        Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE)
    }

    with(intent) {
        putExtra("android.content.extra.SHOW_ADVANCED", true)
        putExtra("android.content.extra.FANCY", true)
        putExtra("android.content.extra.SHOW_FILESIZE", true)
    }
    coroutineScope.launch {
        activityResultLauncher.launch(intent)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Didn't expect that such things can be missing, especially on Android 13 devices.

Those `Intent` actions are not always supported, especially on atypical form factors. Neither Android TV nor Wear OS reliably support them, for example.

> for Galaxy A52 device on Android 13

Technically speaking, for Android 13, your code is not directly using `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`. You are using the result of `storageManager.primaryStorageVolume.createOpenDocumentTreeIntent()`. It is possible that Samsung did not adequately test this particular bit of their Android integration.

> How am I supposed to handle such errors?

Fall back to a plain `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` request if the `storageManager.primaryStorageVolume.createOpenDocumentTreeIntent()` launch throws an `ActivityNotFoundException`.

If that too fails, say "sorry, your device is incompatible".

> Can I even help users to fix such issues

Not generally.

> mb suggest them to install one of File Browser apps from Goolge Play, will it help to choose directory with android.intent.action.OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE for my app?

No.

Comment: Hi, i am also getting ActivityNotFoundException in Android 13 device but in my case I was using ActivityResultCOntracts.OpenDocument(). Put a try/catch in order to use the old fallback Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT; with addCategory(CATEGORY_OPENABLE) and setType("image/jpeg") but it crashes again with ActivityNotFoundException. What can I do? Should i put try/catch again and use ACTION_GET_CONTENT?

Comment: @EzequielAdrian: `ActivityResultCOntracts.OpenDocument` uses `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`, which is why the fallback did not change anything. Falling back to `ActivityResultContracts.GetContent` may work, though bear in mind that there are limits on what you can do with the resulting `Uri`. Notably, you cannot get persistable `Uri` permissions.

Comment: Thankyou @CommonsWare i made a question if you want to post an answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77801474/activitynotfoundexception-in-android-13-redmi-note-10s-action-open-document anyways your comment is really useful!